# How to repeat foreach

Tags: php

This is the code:

```
$dat = getContents($id, $session);
foreach($dat['data']['followings'] as $gg){
    $fid = $gg['fid'];
    $f = follow($fid, $session, $atok);
    echo $f['data']['credits'] . "\n";
}
```

When I'm run this script will get the result on my coin

Ex:

11
12

So, how to repeat the code until I get 50 coin or 100 or something like that?

Because on php just give me 2 result. I can make it to 10 or 50 or 100 but I just can with COPY PASTE these script. You know?

This is how I'm repeat this code:

```
$dat = getContents($id, $session);
foreach($dat['data']['followings'] as $gg){
    $fid = $gg['fid'];
    $f = follow($fid, $session, $atok);
    echo $f['data']['credits'] . "\n";
} 

$dat = getContents($id, $session);
foreach($dat['data']['followings'] as $gg){
    $fid = $gg['fid'];
    $f = follow($fid, $session, $atok);
    echo $f['data']['credits'] . "\n";
}

$dat = getContents($id, $session);
foreach($dat['data']['followings'] as $gg){
    $fid = $gg['fid'];
    $f = follow($fid, $session, $atok);
    echo $f['data']['credits'] . "\n";
}
```

So i can get 6 result. My questions is how to make the code without copy paste this code.

Comment: how many coins do you have in $dat array, only 2 or more than 2

Comment: how many coins do you have in database, only 2 or more than 2? if only 2 then it's unnecessary to go for 50 to 100 coins. If yes then re-write your query  code in such a way that it fetch all coins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $dat = getContents($id, $session);
    foreach ($dat['data']['followings'] as $gg){
        $fid = $gg['fid'];
        $f = follow($fid, $session, $atok);
        echo $f['data']['credits'] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Foreach is a loop to read all indexes of an array, it will repeat itself till it read all indexes of that array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dat = getContents($id, $session);
$counter = 0;
while ($counter < 100) {
    foreach ($dat['data']['followings'] as $gg){
        $fid = $gg['fid'];
        $f = follow($fid, $session, $atok);
        $counter++
        echo $f['data']['credits'] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Can you make the code without end? So the code always running.

Comment: in this case yo don't need the $counter so replace while ($counter < 100) { with while (true) {

Comment: @Anant Yes, i just want make this script always run even when I'm offline. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @HackingtoWin: PHP is not the best choice for this purpose ;)

Comment: If you want to run this code indefinitely, you need to run this script with console, not over browser